# MySQL get total number of orders and sum of total by user

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table called orders where I store information about orders made by an User.

```
order_id    |   user_id |   amount
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1           |   1       |   100
2           |   1       |   200
3           |   2       |   200
4           |   3       |   100
5           |   3       |   100
6           |   4       |   500
```

What I want as final outcome is,
Number of Orders made by an user and total value of those orders.

So in above case output should look like,

```
user_id     |   count   |   sum
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1           |   2       |   300
2           |   1       |   200
3           |   3       |   600
4           |   1       |   500
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Why the user_id 3 has `count = 3` and `sum = 600` shouldn't be 2,  200??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need here is, just a `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` and `SUM` like so:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(User_id) Count,
  SUM(amount) Sum
FROM Orders
GROUP BY user_id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69783/2)

This will give you:

```
| USER_ID | COUNT | SUM |
-------------------------
|       1 |     2 | 300 |
|       2 |     1 | 200 |
|       3 |     2 | 200 |
|       4 |     1 | 500 |
```